# How to make writing output in opposite direction (C++)?

Tags: c++

I created a simple decimal-to-binary program.
Lets say I type in number 8.
It writes back 0001
and I want it to be 1000

how can I do that?

code here:

```
using namespace std;

int translating(int x);

int main()
{
    int x;
    int translate;
    cout << "Write a number: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << endl;
    translate = translating(x);
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}

int translating(int x)
{
    if (x == 1)
    {
        cout << "1";
        return 0;
    }
    if ((x % 2)==1)
    {
        cout << "1";
        return (translating((x-1)/2));
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "0";
        return (translating(x/2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Store the output in a `string` and then reverse it with `std::reverse`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple, so simple you'll kick yourself. Just reverse the order of your output statement and recursive function call. Also fixed a bug.

```
void translating(int x)
{
    if (x < 2)
    {
        cout << x;
        return;
    }
    if ((x % 2)==1)
    {
        translating((x-1)/2);
        cout << "1";
    }
    else
    {
        translating(x/2);
        cout << "0";
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens to stack if I call `translating(0)`?

Comment: @msandiford The OP's code has bugs, my code had the same bugs. I've (hopefully) fixed that bug now.

Comment: Oh, go on.  Fix the rest of it as well.

Comment: @msandiford I don't think I should deviate too much from the OP's code. The idea is right, the OP can fix any further bugs themselves.

Comment: yeah I can see that when I type 0 it overflows, will fix taht adding another if (which is the simpliest for me to understand right now)

Comment: What happens if you call `translating(-3)`, or some other negative number?

Comment: In original code (which is in slovak language) I typed that that you cant enter a negative and/or float number. Simple if (x<0) will then write me an error :)

Comment: and thanks for the reply, void function works good

Answer (score 5):

Instead of writing your output directly, first write it to a temporary string, and then traverse that string from last to first character.

Comment: That's a poor solution. Unnecessary copying.

Comment: What? How many bytes are being copied? Optimizing code that isn't executing millions of times is pointless. His code is executed once, and it's like 10 bytes that are copied.

Comment: It's not a question of optimization, it's a question of code clarity. You answer is to take a algorithm which has been written wrongly and then fix it by copying and reversing. It's better to write the algorithm correctly in the first place.

Comment: Well, to tell you the truth, I didn't even glance at the code. I generally refuse to look at a wall of code, where the OP just pasted his entire program. It's a sign of laziness.

Comment: Since i dont know how strings work yet, I have no idea. Although it seems like its the simpliest solution to my problem.